# how to convert nested XML complex element to Saxon.Sequence in Java?

Tags: java, dom, saxon

I am new to saxon using it to process existing xqueries. I can execute simple xquery with primitive types(simple types) from java class as below:

```
Xquery:
declare function xf:addNumberss($int1 as xs:int,
$int2 as xs:int)
as xs:int {
    <value>{data($int1)+data($int2)}</value>
```

};

```
Java:
final Sequence[] arglist = new Sequence[2];
    arglist[0] = new Int64Value(10);
    arglist[1] = new Int64Value(10);
        arglist[0] = new Int64Value(request.getNo1());
        arglist[1] = new Int64Value(request.getNo2());
        Sequence result = null;
        try {
            result = fn1.call(arglist, controller);
```

where I am getting the expected response. But I am stuck how to pass a complex element as input to Xquery

```
Ex: Xquery

declare function xf:addNumbersByElements($addNumbers1 as element(ns0:addNumbers))
as element(ns0:addNumbersResponse) {
    <ns0:addNumbersResponse>
        <ns0:response>
            <ns0:result>{ data($addNumbers1/ns0:request/ns0:no1) + data($addNumbers1/ns0:request/ns0:no2) }</ns0:result>
        </ns0:response>
    </ns0:addNumbersResponse>

Java:
final Sequence[] arglist = new Sequence[1];
    arglist[0] = (Sequence)addNumType;
```

Unable to convert AdNumType complex type to sequence
    Exception:java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xq.AddNumbersType incompatible with net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence

Could anyone please help how to convert complex type to xquery input in Saxon. Also please suggest any tutorial links available apart from API reference guide.

Thanks

Comment: See http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xquery/api-query/s9api-query.html for an overview and the "Query..." examples in https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.9/samples/java/he/S9APIExamples.java.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check the above links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the s9api interface (classes like `XdmValue`, `XdmAtomicValue`, `XdmNode`) rather than the lower-level interfaces (classes like `NodeInfo`, `Int64Value`, `Sequence`), because the lower-level interfaces expose too much internal complexity and are not so stable between releases.

At the s9api level, you can compile your query using `XQueryCompiler.compile()` to return an `XQueryExecutable`; call `load()` on this to get an `XQueryEvaluator`, and then call `callFunction()` on this to call a specific XQuery function. The `callFunction()` method takes arguments and returns results in the form of `XdmValue` instances. If the query returns a node, it will be in the form of an `XdmNode` instance, and you can run a further query on this `XdmNode` by setting it as the context item for another query using `XQueryEvaluator.setContextItem()`.

If you do want to use the lower-level interface, `Sequence` is an interface and you will have to choose a specific implementation. For a sequence that is a single node, the sub-interface `NodeInfo` is suitable; but you need to be aware that when a function returns a single node, it won't necessarily be returned as an instance of `NodeInfo`, it might for example by a `LazySequence` whose `head()` method needs to be called to obtain the `NodeInfo`. You really don't want to get involved with such complexities if you can avoid it; so use s9api.

Comment: Hi @Michael Kay, Thanks for the explanation. I will try using s9api. just one more question, is this s9api same as saxon api? I have gone through XQJ API which are standardized in Java. Can we use XQJ Api for xquery processing?

Comment: We call it Saxon.Api on .NET, and s9api on Java; they are very similar. You can use XQJ with Saxon, but it has considerable limitations (e.g. nodes can only be materialized in DOM form) so you really only want to use it if portability across XQuery engines is very important to you.